# Excel VBA get URL from newly clicked webpage

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I have written some code to create an IE object, fill in some stuff and click a button to proceed to the next webpage.  After making sure that this new webpage is fully loaded, I want to get the URL of this new webpage but it keeps returning the URL of the first webpage.  Why is this happening?

Comment: Could you include the part of your code where you are returning the URL?

Answer (score 0):

if you wait till page is loaded;

```
Do
Loop Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
```

then the URL should just be

```
ie.Document.URL
```